# Memory not getting freed up using log4net

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, log4net-appender

I am using log4nets `MemoryAppender` for logging debug messages and for some reason even when clearing events the memory does not get freed up. That is a big issue even when running some sample code since the memory usage spikes up to 1GB+.

I've tried forcing the GC to collect and it does lower the usage by ~2MB after clearing events, but then it raises up again later. Clearing events and creating a new appender object does not help at all. When checking the diagnostics window i get the below image. Does anybody have any clue what the leak might be? Why it just keeps filling up?

Appender creation:

```
appender = new MemoryAppender();
LoggerMatchFilter f = new LoggerMatchFilter{ LoggerToMatch = "MemoryLogger" };
appender.AddFilter(f);
appender.ActivateOptions();
GetRootLogger().AddAppender(appender);
Logger logger = (Logger)log.Logger;
logger.AddAppender(appender);
```

Clearing events (executed in overridden Append method):

```
if(m_eventsList.Count > 200)
{
   m_eventsList.Clear();
   GC.Collect();
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Diagnostics Snapshot
[image: Diagnostics Snapshot]

Comment: You could include the header names, otherwise it's hard to follow the numbers...

Comment: Also, please show the code - how do you create the appender, how do you force GC to collect memory.

Comment: It is not obvious how you could have overridden the Append() method but still create the MemoryAppender base class.  So a simple explanation is that your Append override never gets used. And thus the list never gets cleared.  Set a breakpoint on it to make sure.

Comment: I've created a new class that inherits from the base MemoryAppender and there the Append() method is overriden. I've set a breakpoint on it and made sure it clears the events, so that is not the issue sadly :/

Answer (score 1):

Asking Google lead to an [article](https://korhner.github.io/java/debugging/log4j-dynamic-log-leak/) where a similar problem is discussed concerning **log4j**.

There, the problem is caused by creating many loggers with different names.
log4j keeps all those loggers in a `Hashtable`, so they won't be garbage collected.

The recommended solution is to reuse logger objects instead of creating new ones.

So if you create lots of new loggers in your app, this could be the problem.

Comment: I've tried to reuse the old objects, even made it a singleton and sadly the same issue is happening.